# PowerBI filter one table with multiple columns from another table

Tags: powerbi

Here I have two tables:

**Table A**: col_A, col_B, col_C, metric_1, metric_2, metric_3

**Table B**: col_A, col_B, col_C, metric_X, metric_Y, metric_Z

I may need to put them in the report with col_A, col_B, col_C as **shared filters**. col_A, col_B, col_C are many to many relationship, for example, age, country, domain. How could I achieve this?

The solutions I may know are:

1. Pull column col_A, col_B, col_C as filters from table 1, but in this case table 2 doesn't have any relation with table 1 and the filter won't work for table 2. And if I add relation of table 2 with table 1 for col_A, then I couldn't next also add relation for col_B or col_C as only one relation could be added.
2. Another solution is that I would extract col_A, col_B, col_C as a new table for dimensions shared between table 1 and table 2. Then the filters may have better performance as there is less data. However, how could I apply the shared dimension table filter to table 1 and table 2? Or is there way like filter could achieve this?

   `ForAll(Table1, Collect(col_A, Filter(Table2, col_A in FullName).FullName))`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In my opinion, you have two main choices here:**

1. Calculate common dimension tables separately for each `Col_A, Col_B, Col_C`
2. Create a common key in each `Table A, Table B` and create one common dimension table

**Common dimension tables for each column**

For my simplified model of just two common columns, I have created one separate table per dimension:

[image]

The code to create `Dim_A` is just to use `DISTINCT` and `UNION` to get all the possible values from both tables:

```
Dim_A = 
DISTINCT ( 
    UNION ( 
        DISTINCT ( 'Table A'[Col_A] ) , 
        DISTINCT ('Table B'[Col_A] ) 
    ) 
)
```

It is common to hide the key columns on the many-side of relationships, so I have done that in the model too.

This is the approach I would use if this were my data model, especially if `Table A` and `Table B` have columns that are somehow related to `Col_A, Col_B, Col_C` and give these important context. This approach leaves you with greater freedom to normalize your data model.

**Common key in each table**

In Power Query (or where you define your tables), add a column that concatenates the important columns into one key column. In Power Query you can simply add a new custom column and the formula will be:

```
[Col_A]&[Col_b]&[Col_C]
```

You need this common column in BOTH tables, since Power BI does not allow relationships formed by a *combination* of columns, only single-column relationships. Once this is done, you add a single table in the data model using the same style of DAX code as used previously, but you now also need more columns for it to make sense:

```
Dim_All = 
DISTINCT ( 
    UNION ( 
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( 
            'Table A' , 
            "Key" , [Key] , 
            "Col_A" , [Col_A] , 
            "Col_B" , [Col_B] 
        ),
        SELECTCOLUMNS ( 
            'Table B' , 
            "Key" , [Key] , 
            "Col_A" , [Col_A] , 
            "Col_B" , [Col_B] 
        )
    )
)
```

Connect your tables using the `Key` columns, but make sure to specify the correct 1-many setting, depending on your data it might create a 1-1 relationship instead, but you want to avoid this for this data model.
[image]